# Asynctask never finished

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am  trying to work with **Asynctask**, but everytime I'm getting its status, it always returns running.

What is wrong in my code?

This is how I load my asynctask:

```
                LongOperation LongOperation = new LongOperation(finalLink[0], download_data);
                LongOperation.execute();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), LongOperation.getStatus().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This is my asynctask:

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    public Download_data download_data;
    public String link;
    public boolean loading;
    public LongOperation(String link, Download_data download_data){
        this.link = link;
        this.download_data = download_data;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        download_data.download_data_from_link(link);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Executed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are checking status right after executing it:

```
LongOperation.execute();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), LongOperation.getStatus().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

`AsyncTask` runs on background thread. So right after calling `execute()` controls moves to display `Toast`. And by that time, `task` is still running.

You will receive finished status in `onPreExecute` of `AsyncTask`.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void mVoid) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), this.getStatus().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
}
```

In case you are confused about `threads`, do read this: [Java Multithreading](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm)

Comment: It says onPostExecute never used.

Answer (score 0):

The correct signature of [onPostExecute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) is really;

```
protected void onPostExecute (Result result)
```

Since you're not overriding the one in AsyncTask but defining another overload, it (and in its turn `finish()` is never called).

Fix the signature and it should complete as intended.